# Can someone explain what destructive cancellation is as well as how to answer the question?

Tags: approximation

Let $f(x)= \sqrt{x^2 + 1} - 1$ (taking the positive real square root, as usual). When $a = 10^{−3}$, compute $f(a)$, working to $5$ significant figures at every stage of the calculation.

Also it can be shown (algebraically) that

$$f(x) = \frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{{x^2}+1}+1}.$$

Use this expression for $f$ to compute $f(a)$, again working to $5$ significant figures at every stage. Which calculation suffers from destructive cancellation?

After calculating I get that in the first case $f(a)=0.$ In the second case $f(a)=0.0000005.$

Answer (score 0):

You have just seen an example of destructive cancellation.  If you have $1.0001$ and $1.0000$, these are both five digit numbers.  The maximum relative error is about $5E-6$. If you subtract them, you get $0.0001$, which is a single digit number.  This happens whenever you subtract two imprecise numbers that are close to each other.  Look at the two calculations you did and see where this happens.

Comment: I still don't quite understand what destructive cancellation is. Could you provide me with another simple example to explain what it is please?

Comment: I can make another example with different numbers, but it will look just the same.  Say $2.0013-2.0005=0.0008$  Again the first two numbers have five digits while the difference has only one.  The destructive cancellation is the large common value, here the $2$, that disappears.

Comment: Why don't they zeros count as digits in the value 0.0008.

Comment: Leading zeros after the decimal point do not count as significant digits-they just set the scale.  It is like $1000$ has only one significant digit-unless otherwise indicated it is $1000 \pm 500$ as the trailing zeros before the decimal point set the scale. Note that $0.0008$ would be $0.0008 \pm 0.00005$, so there is only one significant digit.